# WordPress Notice: non object property

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, masterslider

I've installed WordPress on localhost using my custom theme. I'm getting this notice on couple of screens:

[image: Error message]

My code is below.

```
$screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $this->sliders_screen_hook_suffix == $screen->id ) {

        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['slider_id'] ) ) {

            $slider_id  = $_REQUEST['slider_id'];
            global $mspdb;
            $custom_fonts = $mspdb->get_slider_field_val( $slider_id, 'custom_fonts' );
```

Comment: if ( $this->sliders_screen_hook_suffix == $screen->id ) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This literally means you're trying to get a property of an object from a variable that isn't an object.

Your code doesn't have line numbers, so I can't tell exactly which is causing the issue, but I can see three attempts to get a property from an object, `$this->sliders_screen_hook_suffix`, `$screen->id`, and `$mspdb->get_slider_field_val( $slider_id, 'custom_fonts' )`. At least one of those variables isn't an object; find out which, and find out the proper way of accessing the data you need.

Comment: if ( $this->sliders_screen_hook_suffix == $screen->id ) {

Comment: Both `$this->` and `$screen->` are attempts to get a property from an object; one of those variables is not an object. Find out which.